# node.js callback strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I face strange callback issue. I expect result return something but it didn't. Someone spot my mistake?

Models

```
module.exports.updateStatus = function(updateObj, callback){
    var order_id = updateObj.order_id,
    order_status = updateObj.order_status;
    Order.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": order_id}, {$set: {order_status: order_status}},{new: true});
```

My Routes

```
var Orders = require('../models/orders');
router.post('/update_status',function(req,res,next){
  var updateObj = {
    'order_status':req.body.order_status,
    'order_id':req.body.order_id
  }
  Orders.updateStatus(updateObj,function(err,result){
    console.log(result) // nothing been return here
  })

})
```

I check my db, the update is actually working fine. I do

```
module.exports.updateStatus = function(updateObj, callback){
        var order_id = updateObj.order_id,
        order_status = updateObj.order_status;
        Order.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": order_id}, {$set: {order_status: order_status}},{new: true},function(err,result){
console.log(result)// it work here
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re never calling `callback` in `updateStatus`, I don’t see why it would ever be called.

If you want it to be called, call it.

The `findOneAndUpdate` statement of `updateStatus` should be:

```
Order.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"_id": order_id},
    {$set: {order_status: order_status}},
    {new: true},
    callback
);
```

Comment: aw what a careless mistake!

Answer (score 0):

you must call callback in updateStatus function

```
exports.updateStatus = function (updateObj, callback) {
    Order.findOneAndUpdate(
        {"_id": updateObj.order_id},
        {$set: {order_status: updateObj.order_status}},
        {new: true},
        callback
    );
}
```